# Properties of conditional probability and independence

Tags: conditional-probability

I have two properties of three random variables $X, W, Z$.

Property 1) $Z \perp W \mid X$

Property 2a) $W \perp X,$

where $\perp$ denotes independence and $\mid$ denotes the standard conditioning. 
My question is, do Properties 1 and 2a hold if and only if

Property 1) $Z \perp W \mid X$

Property 2b) $W \perp X \mid Z$

If not, is 2b) implied by 1) and 2a)? or vice versa? Any comments or thoughts would be appreciated.